# Styling radion button labels individually

Tags: html, css, radio-button

Is it possible to style radio button labels individually?

```
<div class="radio-wrap">
  <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="male">
  <label for="male">Male</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="female">
  <label for="female">Female</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="other" name="gender" value="other">
  <label for="other">Other</label>
</div>
```

I'm trying to style labels but I can't change any classes, ids, or even the HTML code. But input fields have ids and labels have for=" " elements.
Im looking for a selector logic something like:

```
.radio-wrap [1st-label] {
  color: red;
}

.radio-wrap [2nd-label] {
  color: blue;
}

.radio-wrap [3rd-label] {
  color: black;
}
```

Is this something css can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could select the labels in a variety of ways. For example use the various IDs of the inputs and then add the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator). E.g. `#male + label`

```css
#male + label{
color: red;
}

#female + label{
color: blue;
}

#other + label{
color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="radio-wrap">
  <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="male">
  <label for="male">Male</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="female">
  <label for="female">Female</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="other" name="gender" value="other">
  <label for="other">Other</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using [nth-of-type](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp) selector.

```css
.radio-wrap label:nth-of-type(1) {
  color: red;
}

.radio-wrap label:nth-of-type(2) {
  color: blue;
}

.radio-wrap label:nth-of-type(3) {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="radio-wrap">
  <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="male">
  <label for="male">Male</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="female">
  <label for="female">Female</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="other" name="gender" value="other">
  <label for="other">Other</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable comment and time helping me on this